# Is there a .Net wrapper or driver for Cassandra NoSQL database?

Tags: .net, cassandra

Is there a .Net wrapper or driver for Cassandra NoSQL database?
If so could anyone point me at a link to it?

Comment: check Fluent Cassandra:
At this link
https://github.com/fluentcassandra/fluentcassandra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several, as can be seen on the Cassandra Wiki page for [ClientOptions](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions):

- [Aquiles](http://aquiles.codeplex.com/)
- [Hector Sharp](http://www.hectorsharp.com)
- [Fluent Cassandra](http://github.com/managedfusion/fluentcassandra)

Comment: Out of these three possibilities.., Oded would you choose Aquiles?  Also is there a way to use Hadoop or even better yet Hadoop and Hive with one of these ClientOptions?  If not could you see using possibly DryadLINQ with one of these?

Comment: @apolfj - I haven't worked with Hadoop/Hive, so I can't comment on how any of these would work with it. If you write up some code to test all three, that would be your best bet to see how well suited they are.

Comment: @apolfj You could keep your eye on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1434 for the hive driver to cassandra (would let you use any existing hive connector) for open source, or for running hadoop on top of cassandra, see http://www.datastax.com/products/enterprise

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend Hector Sharp due to there are some concurrencies issues when it is over heavy traffic.

Here i copy what aquiles gives:

- A 3.5 .NET friendly interface to cassandra operations. You operates against cassandra as you would operate against an SQL (See examples)
- Connection Pool with warm-up and size control capabilities
- An Endpoint Manager to manage all the entrypoint nodes to one cluster. It will automatically distribute the connections against all the cluster endpoints defined, and will check for healthiness of the nodes with a defensive node health check strategy.
  Command parameter Validation:
  Input Parameter Completeness (no more going against a cluster to detect that you are missing a parameter!)
  Prior Keyspace and ColumnFamily existance validation against a cluster information (retrieved on initialization)
- a simple and user-friendly configuration section to configure all your clusters
- You can handle more than 1 cluster in your application
- You can configure what ConnectionPool you want to use and its internal parameters.
- You can choose what EndpointManager you want to use
- You can choose what Transport do you want to use, and even when using TBufferedTransport you can set the length of the buffer!

I didn't check FluentCassandra, but it only works over .NET 4.0, so if you are still working with 3.5 it will be a little difficult to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but one of the top Google results, so I thought I'd provide some input.  Also, in light of some new information I thought I would update my answer.

Information on the official [DataStax C# CQL driver can be found here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/csharp-driver/whatsNew2.html).  DataStax provides plenty of [good documentation and examples](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/csharp-driver/quick_start/qsQuickstart_c.html) for it.

The **latest version** ([2.5, released on Feb 5, 2015](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/csharp-driver-cassandra-new-mapper-linq-improvements)) of this driver has some exciting new features, foremost that it **now has a Mapper/ORM** component.  To get it, go to the [project's GitHub repository](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver), or simply search for "datastax" in NuGet.

In terms of support and stability, you cannot go wrong by using a DataStax-supported driver.